# Performance forecasting

Tags: sql-server, excel-formula, forecasting, nonlinear-functions

I am completely new to forecasting and I am working with arrears figures and collection rates and have been asked to produce a forecast of performance over the next 12 months.
I have access to Excel and SQL Server - can anyone recommend an accurate method to complete this?
I need figures as opposed to graphs.

Comment: There are entire books written on forecasting using statistical analysis, it is going to be hard to summarise this into a short answer unless you narrow your question down hugely. Even then, Stackoverflow is for programming specific questions and answers, I am not sure this would fit in and [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) may be more appropriate

Comment: Thanks @GarethD - as I said I'm completey new and just thought I would try my luck here. I'll give Cross Validated a try and narrow my question a little. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[FB Prohpet](https://research.fb.com/prophet-forecasting-at-scale/) is something you should give a try for forecasting. I have been using it to forecast sales in various stores.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things that you read online would direct you to statistical packages in R or Python for forecasting. Note that both are free.

But if you really want to stick to Excel and still do some point forecasting, you could do worse than performing a simple autoregressive model, e.g by regressing the values at t on e.g. the values at t-1.

A very quick google search gave me a link to this website:
http://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/autoregressive-processes/